# Expect the creation of a new object

Tags: ruby, rspec, stub

I need to write an expectation that a new object will be created in a payment system. Code included from `order.rb` and `order_spec.rb` (`Order` class is [here](https://github.com/benhawker/ruby-order-processing/blob/master/lib/order.rb)):

```
#order.rb 

def confirm_order(method_of_payment)
  if credit_card_but_products_out_stock?(method_of_payment)
    raise "Cannot make credit card payment now, as some products are out of stock" 
  end

  order_total
  Payment.new(method_of_payment, self.total)
end

#order_spec.rb

it 'it creates a new payment object if method_of_payment is valid and order.total is > 0' do
  order.add_product(product, 3)
  order.confirm_order(:credit_card)
  #Expect that a new payment object is created.
end
```

I want to understand how I can write the appropriate spec to test that the new Payment object is created. I found [this article](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/mocking-with-rspec-doubles-and-expectations) from Semaphore CI useful, but am not sure about a solution. I am pretty sure I should be creating a test double of some sort, and then maybe a method stub to `allow(order).to receive(:confirm_order).and_return(#new_object??)`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're unit testing the `Order` class, then you shouldn't be mocking or stubbing the `Order` class. You could set an expectation on the `Payment` class to return a mock that you can then further assert as the return value of `confirm_order` method.

```rb
let(:payment) { double :payment }

it "returns a payment" do
  expect(Payment).to receive(:new).with(:credit_card).and_return(payment)

  order.add_product(product, 3)
  expect(order.confirm_order(:credit_card)).to eq(payment)
end
```

This way, you are mocking the dependencies of your `Order` class, without altering the `Order` class, which is much safer as mocking method on `Order` could easily create false-positive test results.